# PHP if statement not working changing my array properly

Tags: php, arrays

Can you please explain why is this always passing the first if statement condition, it's obviously not right?!

Thank you very much for your help!

```
$meal_plan = array();

  // meal macros
  $meal_macros = array['meals_per_day' => 6];
  $test = $meal_macros['meals_per_day'];

  if( $test == 4 ) {
    $meal_plan = array(
      'breakfast' => [],
      'lunch' => [],
      'snack' => [],
      'dinner' => []
    );  
  } elseif( $test == 5 ) {
    $meal_plan = array(
      'breakfast' => [],
      'snack' => [],
      'lunch' => [],
      'snack' => [],
      'dinner' => []
    );  
  } elseif( $test == 6 ) {
    $meal_plan = array(
      'breakfast' => [],
      'snack' => [],
      'lunch' => [],
      'snack' => [],
      'dinner' => [],
      'snack' => []
    ); 
  } else {
    $meal_plan = array(
      'breakfast' => [],
      'snack' => [],
      'lunch' => [],
      'snack' => [],
      'dinner' => [],
      'snack' => []
    ); 
  }
```

P>S>
Please ignore this text, i am writing this so i can post this question. The post filter is telling me i don't have enough text in the question only code, so i am adding some. LOL

Comment: Because all `if`s do the same thing? Also `array['meals_per_day' => 6]` is not the correct syntax, and you should see at least a warning.

Comment: what value you are getting in `$test`?

Comment: It does not always pass the first condition, it just looks like that as the resulting arrays are all the same.

Comment: @PHPdev Getting 6 for $test as expected.

Comment: array syntax is error try this one $meal_macros = array('meals_per_day' => 6);

Comment: check this : https://eval.in/986887 you will understand your issue

Comment: check `gettype($test)` if it is a string then pls change your conditions as `else if($test == "6")`

Comment: your code is not passing into first if...it's entering into `else if($test == "6")` only pls echo inside your `else if($test == "6")`,i think duplicate elements get removed.please post your code how your are displaying your result

Comment: @PHPdev why do you say that? It's not a string. Where did you get that impression?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i'm not sure the type of the value.that's why i asked to check

Comment: @PHPdev I was responding to the now deleted comment where you were positive it was a string (or you accidentaly phrased it in a way that would mean that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was, you cannot use the same key in the array! I was using 'snack' multiple times as key in the same array. Thanks for the input everyone!